# cfwheels - deleting records with multi-level nested properties

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I've got a model that has a nested property, which has more nested properties.

Let's say `house` hasMany `pets` has many `legs`

It works easily enough when there is just one level, but with two, I'm getting an error when deleting the `pets`, because the `petsID` is a foreign key in the legs table, and cfwheels is not deleting it first. I know I could just do the deletion myself with an extra command, but I'm wondering if there is a setting I missed that allows this kind of deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the `dependent` argument on the association definitions?

```
// In `House.cfc`
hasMany(name="pets", dependent="delete");

// In `Pet.cfc`
hasMany(name="legs", dependent="delete");
```

When you call `house.delete()`, it should delete any associated pets, which then would delete any associated legs as well.

See [hasMany() documentation](http://cfwheels.org/docs/function/hasMany) and the ["Dependencies" section of the Associations chapter](http://cfwheels.org/docs/chapter/associations).

Comment: On a side note, you could change the `dependent` to `deleteAll` on the `legs` association if you don't need to instantiate the `Leg` objects for any callbacks or dependencies. You would need to keep the `pets` association at `delete` though because it would need to instantiate those objects to run the `delete` dependency. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks Chris, I see now where I went wrong. I was using `deleteAll` instead of `delete`